# Fire trucks put out fire

Tags: grammar

1. Fire trucks put out fire.
2. Fire trucks put out fires.

Which form would be more natural, fire or fires?

Comment: I think it's "Fire trucks put out the fire", like *After fire trucks put out the file, ...* People can put out fires, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 1 needs an article (a, the) before the word fire - which article depend on if you are talking about a specific fire (use 'the') or a fire you do not know about (use 'a')'. This sentence is a specific incident of multiple fire trucks putting out a fire.

A newspaper headline could read:

> "Fire trucks put out fire"

as they tend to omit articles (a, the). The inherent sentence is "Fire trucks put out a fire".

Sentence 2 is a statement of fact, such as 'Rocks are hard' and 'Bears go to the toilet in the woods". You could not use the singular of trucks here.

Comment: Thank you. Couldn't fire without articles be used as uncountable noun like water ( fire trucks use water to put out) ?

Comment: Joe - you're right, it could. However to me, that implies that fire trucks put out fire in general, as opposed to 'fires', which implies separate fires that aren't wanted. Difficult to explain. If you asked a child what fire trucks (or firefighters) do, they might say "Put out fires" but less likely to say "Put out fire".

Comment: Thank you again. Can you give an extra effort for this difficult to explain part? if what firetrucks are doing is a general job, then general fire should fit to explain what they do.

Comment: Hi Joe. This is one of those questions that make you question your own language and why you say things the way you do (which I never thought about before learning French). I can almost visualise this as a hierarchy with "Put out fire' as the broadest description of what they do, "Put out fires" as more specific, "Get called in an emergency to put out unwanted, uncontrolled fires" as yet more specific etc, etc. Not very helpful, I'm afraid, but I'm having trouble explaining it!

Comment: I just realised that I thought your original question was referring to a specific case of fire trucks putting out a fire (hence my newspaper headline example). I realise now that you were talking about what fire trucks do in general (i.e. "put out fire" or "put out fires". Both are equally valid, but I still think 2. is slightly more common.